# key board combination to recover from frozen screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde

I have had a problem with my kde screen freezing with a kwin_x11 kde bug taking 100% cpu
I cannot get another getty session with cnt-alt-f2 for instance
There is a direct boot that by passes every thing with alt-sysrq-b that does a hard reboot
What I really want is a command that can give me another session so I can kill the buggy process - what can I use?